# Is there a better way of Iterating over a list to make list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, zip, python-itertools

I have a list `L = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']`
and variables `x = 'Name', y = 'Age'`

I'm trying to merge them into list of tuples with this code,

```
from itertools import cycle    
list(zip(L, cycle([x]) , cycle([y])))
```

This is the output I get, which is my desired output as well.

```
[('A', 'Name', 'Age'), ('B', 'Name', 'Age'), ('C', 'Name', 'Age'), ('D', 'Name', 'Age'), ('E', 'Name', 'Age')]
```

But I want to know, if there's a better way of doing this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be OK or did I miss something?

```
[(l, x, y) for l in L]
```

Comment: Holy cow. How did I miss this!!! Thank you. Guess I had enough coding for the day!! I should rest.